# How to fill in missing sequence lines in a TSV file

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite

I am still a beginner so for starters sorry for the question with likely an obvious answer, and sorry for the messy code, but I have files with ten thousands of lines. I am working with a certain window frame technique to slide along my files so I need to be sure that every window is in there. However, some of my input file misses certain lines so I tried to write a code in Python to add these lines and the information I want in them, to make the file complete. This is what the code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

outfile = open ("missing_test.txt", "w")

with open("add_missing.txt", "r") as file:
    last_line = 0   #This is where it starts for bin 1
    lines = []
    header_line = next(file)
    outfile.write(header_line)
    CHROM = 'BABA_1'
    for line in file:     #go through every line to check its existence and rewrite to new file
        nums = line.split("\t")
        num1 = nums[0]        #no integer because this is a string: name individual
        num2 = int(nums[1])   #integer for window
        num3 = int(nums[2])   #integer for coverage (here always 10000 to met treshold)
        num4 = int(nums[3])   #integer for SNP count   
        if num1 == CHROM:     #
            while num2 != last_line + 10000:
                #A line is missing, so a new line is added with 0 SNPs:
                NUM2 = last_line + 10000   # New window, the one that was missing
                NUM4 = 0   #0 SNPs found
                #lines.append((num1, NUM2, num3, NUM4))
                OUTLINE = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (num1, NUM2, num3, NUM4) #write new line to outfile       
                outfile.write(OUTLINE + "\n")
                last_line += 10000
            lines.append((num1,num2,num3,num4))
            last_line += 10000    #also add 10000 here otherwise the while loop makes no sense
            outline = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (num1, num2, num3, num4)
            outfile.write(outline + "\n")   #write all existing lines to outfile

        else:
            CHROM = num1
            last_line = 0

outfile.close()
```

So this works perfectly fine as long as the first window of the first "CHROM" is equal to 0, which is not always the case. And in this latter case the loop will be infinite. This is for example what input and DESIRED output looks like:

Input:

```
indiv   window  coverage    SNP
BABA_1  20000   10000   7
BABA_1  30000   10000   1
BABA_1  50000   10000   2
BABA_1  60000   10000   3
BABA_1  80000   10000   1
BABA_10 20000   10000   1
BABA_10 30000   10000   16
BABA_10 80000   10000   9
```

Desired output:

```
indiv   window  coverage    SNP
BABA_1  10000   10000   0
BABA_1  20000   10000   7
BABA_1  30000   10000   1
BABA_1  40000   10000   0
BABA_1  50000   10000   2
BABA_1  60000   10000   3
BABA_1  70000   10000   0
BABA_1  80000   10000   1
BABA_10 10000   10000   0
BABA_10 20000   10000   1
BABA_10 30000   10000   16
BABA_10 40000   10000   0
BABA_10 50000   10000   0
BABA_10 60000   10000   0
BABA_10 70000   10000   0
BABA_10 80000   10000   9
```

I have been struggling and searching for answers to get this while loop of mine working without going on infinitely but I seriously do not see my flaw. Does anyone have a tip for me on how I can solve this?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, you want to quit the `while` loop if that "CHROM" is not equal to 0, is this right?

Comment: No the CHROM is actually just a string, and once that string changes I want to start over

Comment: You need to care about case-sensitivity. `num1` and `NUM1` are not the same.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your window lines are all from 10000 to 80000 in streps of 10000, right? And the number of these sets equals the number of distinct BABA_*

Comment: Hi, I realize that it's actually why I did it, because the capital letter variables only come in once a line is missing and I will add it myself. NUM2 will be the new window, and NUM4 will be always 0 in that case, the rest is the same.

Comment: What is `lines` good for?

Comment: No the windows go way further than 80000, this is just a subset but yes it is always in steps of 10000, and as soon as the string in column 1 changes it starts again from the first window (might be 0, might be 10000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

outfile = open ("missing_test.txt", "w")

def write_line(indiv, window, coverage, snp):
    outline = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (indiv, window, coverage, snp)
    outfile.write(outline)

with open("add_missing.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    write_line(*lines.pop(0).rstrip().split("\t"))
    first_line = lines[0].split("\t")
    last_indiv = first_line[0]
    last_window = int(first_line[1])

    for line in lines:
        indiv, window, coverage, snp = line.split("\t")
        window = int(window)
        coverage = int(coverage)
        snp = int(snp)

        if indiv == last_indiv:
            # If the current window is higher than expected,
            # insert a line with the missing window.
            # Repeat until we get to the expected window.
            while window > last_window + 10000:
                write_line(indiv, last_window + 10000, coverage, 0)
                last_window += 10000
            last_window = window
        else:
            last_indiv = indiv
            last_window = window
        write_line(indiv, window, coverage, snp)
```

What it does not contain is the expectation of a certain window number being the first in a given `indiv`, since you didn't define that behaviour and your comment about this was rather confusing.

---

Content of missing_test.txt after running this script:

> ```
> indiv window  coverage    SNP
> BABA_1    20000   10000   7
> BABA_1    30000   10000   1
> BABA_1    40000   10000   0
> BABA_1    50000   10000   2
> BABA_1    60000   10000   3
> BABA_1    70000   10000   0
> BABA_1    80000   10000   1
> BABA_10   20000   10000   1
> BABA_10   30000   10000   16
> BABA_10   40000   10000   0
> BABA_10   50000   10000   0
> BABA_10   60000   10000   0
> BABA_10   70000   10000   0
> BABA_10   80000   10000   9
> ```

Comment: That looks a little more neat thanks for that! Does this one work for you with the specified input subset? I do not get any output written into the output file (I added a close statement below)  ?

Comment: Shame on me for not trying it out. I've tried and fixed a few leftover bugs.

Comment: In case you need all entries to start at window 0 or 10000, I'll leave this to you as an exercise :-D

Comment: I cannot thank you enough I will get it working with the right startbin/window. Again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach which first builds an empty list and then assigns any exist entries into it before writing them as rows to the output:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('add_missing.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('missing_test.txt', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t', skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for k, g in itertools.groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[0]):
        empty = [[k, x * 10000, 10000, 0] for x in range(1, 9)]
        for row in g:
            empty[int(row[1]) / 10000 - 1] = row

        csv_output.writerows(empty)
```

Giving you:

```
indiv   window  coverage    SNP
BABA_1  10000   10000   0
BABA_1  20000   10000   7
BABA_1  30000   10000   1
BABA_1  40000   10000   0
BABA_1  50000   10000   2
BABA_1  60000   10000   3
BABA_1  70000   10000   0
BABA_1  80000   10000   1
BABA_10 10000   10000   0
BABA_10 20000   10000   1
BABA_10 30000   10000   16
BABA_10 40000   10000   0
BABA_10 50000   10000   0
BABA_10 60000   10000   0
BABA_10 70000   10000   0
BABA_10 80000   10000   9
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! I didn't even know about `iterools.groupby` until now.